# Are performance counters the best way to implement and average per second count?

Tags: .net, performancecounter

I want to include some sort of performance counts in my application. Are Windows Performance counters (Perfmon) counters the best way to go. I am just worried that maybe it is too much overhead for what am I wanting which is just a simple average per second count. Is it better to just roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Perfmon works quite well.
To minimize any overhead, run Perfmon on a remote machine.
I've used Perfmon to collect serious, in-depth, and valuable performance data on a BizTalk server from a development machine on the same network and every part of the process worked very well.  I wouldn't even consider any other method of collecting the same kind of performance data without very strong evidence.

Answer (score -2):

No, performance counters are sloppy and should not be used for 'critical' counters.
On high utilized systems performance counters can be updated very slowly and can even be incorrect.

Comment: [citation required].  Performance counters are used to measure system critical events like page faults/second, processor interrupts/second etc.

Comment: There are quite a few resources out there for how to create your own performance counters using .Net. If this practice was so bad wouldn't there be more warning against this. Especially on the MSDN? Looking at all the counters available in PerfMon Microsoft has used them everywhere and for all sorts of things. If this is bad then is there an alternative that I can use? I imagine rolling your own counters etc can be quite buggy.

Comment: Although it can be true that overuse of perf ctrs can negatively impact overall performance, they are absolutely vital to serious instrumentation. Every major Microsoft server product uses them extensively; there's no way the SQL Server team is going to allow sloppy perf ctrs to drag down their scores against Oracle et al. I reject your claim as uninformed. I defy you to provide a better method that has the same interoperability and remote management potential.

Comment: @AlanMcBee build one yourself, it has the same interoperability and remote management potention, it might not be feasible though :) However Performance Counter can negatively impact system performance and might not deliver per second averages that actually give a clear view of what is going on in a second. If you need really fine grained profiling information running a simple counter in you own application isn't that hard to implement.

Comment: PerfCtrs should not substitute for code profiling when you need subsecond performance tuning; I agree with that. But the original question is to the efficacy of PerfCtrs in general. Your response suggested avoiding them in general, and that's bad advice. They are recommended in most cases where instrumentation is needed. A simple NumberOfItems32 counter can be updated in only 14ns longer than an Interlocked.Increment (Intel Core i3 2-core 2.27GHz), or 7 milliseconds longer for 1,000,000 updates. Custom-made counters are usually examples of the NIH anti-pattern.